# Cannot get table row selection working with semantic-ui table

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to adopt Semantic-UI and I'm having some trouble.  I'd like to get row selection to work in a table.

I'm using their sample HTML below:

```
        <table class="ui selectable celled table">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yjuoqdcy/

You can see that hovering over the rows does nothing.  I'm guessing I'm missing some sort of behavior or event hook up but I cannot find much in the documentation.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Add `tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}` to your CSS. Updated [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/yjuoqdcy/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are using an old version (1.11.8) of the Semantic UI framework. Upgrading to the the latest version will allow you to use row selection without the need of custom CSS.

`selectable table` was introduced in version 2.0.0. - [Release notes](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES.md#version-200---june-30-2015)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<table class="ui selectable celled table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>No Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jamie</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Denied</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This will likely answer a lot of my other questions too.

Comment: I hope it does. The framework has a rough transition period if you're coming from other frameworks like Bootstrap and such, but it's worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the background of the cell to change colour when you mouse over it?

If so all you need is something like this.

```
table tr:hover {
  background: #CCCCFF;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/cae2k9fy/

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom style to the rows using `tr:hover`. Do styling as necessary with

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/yjuoqdcy/3/